# Resample multiple columns Pandas

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

How can I resample my dataframe over multiple columns to obtain a new statistic?

For example, I have a dataframe with indexed by seconds with two columns (amount, quantities) and I would like to resample() to minutes to a new column based on amount * quantities .

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggreagte function like  `sum`, `mean` and then multiple columns:

```
df = df.resample('T').sum()
df['new'] = df.amount * df.quantities
```

Comment: Thanks @Jezrael, in this example, this would work but imagine I wanted to get the correlation between amount and quantities.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.